# Print HTML text to a word doc c# (Using Interop.Word)

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I'm using Interop.Word in order to load a doc template, append some long text and save the doc. The question I have is regarding rendering content as HTML within the word document.

Is there any option via Interop.Word to append text to the document so that the output in the doc will be rendered as HTML content? 
(with all the colors and tables and so on).
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Cal.png)

Comment: Hello, Can you please post your code in the question and not as an image. Thanks

Comment: No, Word does not support displaying HTML content. If HTML is put on the clipboard and pasted into Word, it will be converted to Word content, which will try to "mimic" the HTML as far as Word is able. I've never seen or heard of it being done, but *theoretically*, if there were an OLE Server program installed on the machine that could display HTML format, HTML content could be inserted as an OLE object containing that content. It would be limited to one page in size.